# Find an algorithm to balance success rate and cost

Tags: algorithm

Assume I have a task that contains 2 steps. Each step has a success rate and  a cost. Each step can be assigned to one or more people to complete to increase the success rate. Can anyone help me to find an algorithm to balance them?

For example:

A task with 2 steps. Step 1 has success rate 50% and cost $1. Step 2 has success 75% and cost $2. If I assign each step to only one person, the overall success rate will be 50% * 75% = 37.5%. The threshold I want to reach is 80%.

In this case, I should assign step 1 to 3 people to get 87.5% success rate, and assign step 2 to 2 people to get 93.75%. Then the overall success rate is 82.08%

But I don't know how to implement it with an algorithm.

Update:

Assign to more people means multiply people execute this step at the same time. if there are 3 people to execute a 50% success rate task. The possibility that at least one person succeed is 1 - 0.5^3 = 87.5%.

Comment: How does `I should assign step 1 to 3 people to get 87.5% success rate` get you 87.5% ? is there an upper bound for the number of people?

Comment: It is the success rate that at least one person succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually very easy once you make the following observation: in order to reach an overall success rate above a threshold T, no individual success rate can be below T. Otherwise, since the overall success rate is the product of each individual one, you would need at least one rate above 1 (>100%) to balance out.

In your example, you need each individual success rate to be above 80%, and the minimum number of people needed for each task is, as you worked out, 3 for step 1 and 2 for step 2.

An individual success rate S is calculated based on the base success rate B, and the number of people N, using the formula `S = 1 - (1-B)^N`. What you want to find is N: `N = ln(1-S)/ln(1-B)`. Finally, since you need `S > T`, you get `N = ceil[ln(1-T)/ln(1-B)]`.

Calculate this N for each step and you get an overall success rate above the threshold. Moreover, no N can be smaller, otherwise the corresponding success rate, and so the overall success rate, would be below the threshold.

You mentionned that each step has a cost, but is does not play any role in the problem since there is a hard limit on the number of people for each individual step.

Comment: Thanks for your brilliant solution, but can you explain a little bit more about how did you conclude the formula N = ln(1-S)/ln(1-B)? The cost seems not useful in this example, but I'm not sure if there are other cases that include multiply answers and I will need to pick the one with lowest cost.

Comment: I got it! To find the solution with the lowest cost, I only need to guarantee that the rate of every single step is higher than the threshold and then add the one with lowest cost to increase overall rate.

Comment: The formula is just maths: `S = 1-(1-B)^N`,  `(1-B)^N = 1-S`, `ln((1-B)^N) = ln(1-S)`, `N*ln(1-B) = ln(1-S)`, `N = ln(1-S)/ln(1-B)`. The solution with the lowest cost _always is_ the solution with the fewest people, which _always is_ the solution with the fewest people per step.

Comment: The question contains a bad example. A better example would be that task 1 has a success rate of 47%, and task 2 has a success rate of 58%. Thus with 3 people, task 1 has a success rate of 85.1%. And with 2 people, task 2 has a success rate of 82.4%. But overall the success rate is `.851 * .824 = .701`. So the overall success rate is 70% which is below the 80% target. So now you have to exceed the hard lower limit on the number of people, and therefore the cost to add people becomes a factor.